# Как передать значения из json в другую функцию

Tags: json

Может код тугой, но я ВООБЩЕ новичек.

```
 App = function(){
     var ajaxStack = [];
     this.pushAjaxResult = function(ajaxResult)
     {
         ajaxStack.push(ajaxResult);
     }
     this.getLastAjaxResult = function()
     {
         return ajaxStack[ajaxStack.length - 1];
     } };
 app = new App();

    $.get('/testo.php',function(Arr){
        var x = JSON.parse(Arr);
        app.populateTable(x);
    }   ,"json")
app.populateTable = function(x) {       
    var buf =[];
    for (var i = 0;i<x.length;i++){
        buf[i]=[i,x[i]];
     }
     };
```

Необходимо передать в функцию plot массив  buf

> plot = $.plot($("#placeholder"),
>                   [ { data: buf ....
>                     });

Comment: http://segfault.kiev.ua/smart-questions-ru.html#grovelling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во первых, не надо делать JSON.parse, т.к. уже есть "json", Arr - **уже** массив(или объект).

во вторых, вы слишком наворачиваете, просто вызовите $.plot в хэндлере запроса.

```
$(function () {
    var $placeholder=$('#placeholder');
    function populateTable(x) {
        var buf = [];
        for (var i = 0,l=x.length; i < l; i++) {
            buf[i] = [i, x[i]];
        }
        var plot=$.plot($placeholder, [{
            data: buf //....
        }]);
        var axes=plot.getAxes(); //что за топоры ? может Axis ?
    }

    $.get('/testo.php',populateTable,"json");
    // вот здесь данные еще не получены, но $.get() завершен.
});
```

Comment: по поводу дальнейших операций с plot. как я уже говорил, вы видимо хотите ещё какие-то действия совершать с полученным графиком, для этого вам просто необходимо понять асинхронное программирование. все просто. надо вызывать все что относится к plot. после получения данных, т.е. в хэндлерах запроса. есть куча способов это делать.

Comment: я наверно просто ничего не понимаю в веб-программировании, и здесь СОВЕРШЕННО другая логика (исходя из опыта C#), но почему нужно все загонять в одну функцию. Почему из одной функции нельзя просто массив передать как я хочу. Что в этом сложного? Если все загонять в одну функцию, там вся логика рушится , слишком много обращений к plot. не хочу терять функционал и все переписывать

Comment: потому что, данные получаются **асинхронно** не нужно все в одну функцию загонять, просто нужно вызывать ваш рисовальщик когда данные уже получены. Рассматривайте это как событие. скажем, можете ли вы получить координаты клика до того как пользователь кликнул ? Тут так-же, отправляем запрос и в функции callback ждем ответ.

Comment: не ну понятно что нужно знать че рисовать. даже если в одну функцию загнать. 
$(function () { 
    $.get('/testo.php',function(Arr){
   ...
     }
  plot = $.plot("#placeholder", [
   { data: buf, label: "sin(x) = -0.00"} ...
пам-парам нарисовал он график. дальше нужно из функции получить данные относительно положения курсора 
 var dataset = plot.getData();
   ...
и дальше в области видимости одной функции он не может обратиться к функции plot

Comment: ну сделайте `var plot;` выше, только не  обращайтесь к ней до того как данные получите.

Answer (score 0):

Дык вы не правильно функцию в класс добавили надо так:

```
App = function(){
     var ajaxStack = [];
     this.pushAjaxResult = function(ajaxResult)
     {
         ajaxStack.push(ajaxResult);
     }
     this.getLastAjaxResult = function()
     {
         return ajaxStack[ajaxStack.length - 1];
     } };

App.prototype.populateTable = function(x) {       
    var buf =[];
    for (var i = 0;i<x.length;i++){
        buf[i]=[i,x[i]];
     }
    return buf;
     };

app = new App();

$(function () { 
    $.get('/testo.php',function(Arr){
        var x = JSON.parse(Arr);
        var buf = app.populateTable(x);
        plot = $.plot($("#placeholder"),
                  [ { data: buf ....
                    });
    }   ,"json")
```

Comment: мля, даж не зная сделал правильно, хех. да я знаю что так работать будет (в другом месте делал так). НО мне именно передать надо, т.к к функции plot идет обращение дальше, а если её в функцию обернуть, то не могу вызвать 
' var axes = plot.getAxes();'